# Parse a complex xml file with Python

Tags: python, xml, nested, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse a network traffic matrix file that is in XML format. It includes the traffic volumes between the origin (source) and destination nodes. What I have is a sequence traffic matrix, which means that the traffic is evolving over time and represented by time sequence 0 to time sequence N. As an example, I attach the below file that includes the XML traffic matrix in which, there are two time sequences (i.e. seq 0 and 1) and at each time sequence there are two origins (i.e. 20 and 21) and a set of destinations (i.e. 32, 33, 34, 35, 28, 29, 30, 31). The float numbers are the traffic volume in Mbps.

What I'm looking for is to parse such matrix and find the traffic volume of each [origin--destination] over the time.

For example: I'm interested to get the following information only from the file,

```
            Time seq"0"
                       Origin --  Destination --  Traffic volume

                        20    --      32     --   0.278971163226 
                        .
                        . 
                        .
                        20   - -      31     --   0
                        21    --      32     --   0.0720389596699 
                        .
                        . 
                        .
                        21   - -      31     --   0.646495362713
            Time seq"1"
                       
                        20    --      32     --   0.348919367445 
                        .
                        . 
                        .
                        20   - -      31     --   0.348919367445
                        21    --      32     --   0.264369876118 
                        .
                        . 
                        .
                        21   - -      31     --   0
```

Here is the XML file.

```
-<traffic-matrix type="sequence">
 -<time seq="0">
   <property name="volume_unit" type="string">Mbps</property>
  -<origin id="20" id.type="int">
     <destination id="32" id.type="int">0.278971163226</destination>
     <destination id="33" id.type="int">0.21534822478</destination>
     <destination id="34" id.type="int">0.417878716061</destination>
     <destination id="35" id.type="int">0.126812437403</destination>
     <destination id="28" id.type="int">0.0</destination>
     <destination id="29" id.type="int">0.377649042951</destination>
     <destination id="30" id.type="int">0.230012161609</destination>
     <destination id="31" id.type="int">0.0</destination>
   </origin>
  -<origin id="21" id.type="int">
    <destination id="32" id.type="int">0.0720389596699</destination>
    <destination id="33" id.type="int">0.0194404241696</destination>
    <destination id="34" id.type="int">0.416078923017</destination>
    <destination id="35" id.type="int">0.271277529292</destination>
    <destination id="28" id.type="int">0.0219082425921</destination>
    <destination id="29" id.type="int">0.0</destination>
    <destination id="30" id.type="int">0.0645726634169</destination>
    <destination id="31" id.type="int">0.646495362713</destination>
   </origin>
 </time>
-<time seq="1">
   <property name="volume_unit" type="string">Mbps</property>
  -<origin id="20" id.type="int">
    <destination id="32"id.type="int">0.348919367445</destination>
    <destination id="33" id.type="int">0.0</destination>
    <destination id="34" id.type="int">0.0</destination>
    <destination id="35" id.type="int">0.0</destination>
    <destination id="28" id.type="int">0.0</destination>
    <destination id="29" id.type="int">0.11926219607</destination>
    <destination id="30" id.type="int">0.0</destination> 
    <destination id="31" id.type="int">0.128091658298</destination>
   </origin>
  -<origin id="21" id.type="int">
    <destination id="32" id.type="int">0.264369876118</destination>
    <destination id="33" id.type="int">0.0</destination>
    <destination id="34" id.type="int">0.136801239629</destination>
    <destination id="35" id.type="int">0.172101959022</destination> 
    <destination id="28" id.type="int">0.289540759798</destination>
    <destination id="29" id.type="int">0.0</destination>
    <destination id="30" id.type="int">0.519869498363</destination>
    <destination id="31" id.type="int">0.0</destination>
   </origin>
 </time>
</traffic-matrix>
```

Comment: The question is tagged "python". What have you tried? What is the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to solve the problem with Python, I have tried the xml.etree but it did not work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution with `beautifulsoup` library - used here to parse XML. This script will create pandas DataFrame from the data (`xml_data` is your XML from the question):

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_data, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for d in soup.select('destination'):
    all_data.append({
        'Time_seq': int(d.find_previous('time')['seq']),
        'Origin': int(d.find_previous('origin')['id']),
        'Destination': int(d['id']),
        'Traffic volume': d.text
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    Time_seq  Origin  Destination   Traffic volume
0          0      20           32   0.278971163226
1          0      20           33    0.21534822478
2          0      20           34   0.417878716061
3          0      20           35   0.126812437403
4          0      20           28              0.0
5          0      20           29   0.377649042951
6          0      20           30   0.230012161609
7          0      20           31              0.0
8          0      21           32  0.0720389596699
9          0      21           33  0.0194404241696
10         0      21           34   0.416078923017
11         0      21           35   0.271277529292
12         0      21           28  0.0219082425921
13         0      21           29              0.0
14         0      21           30  0.0645726634169
15         0      21           31   0.646495362713
16         1      20           32   0.348919367445
17         1      20           33              0.0
18         1      20           34              0.0
19         1      20           35              0.0
20         1      20           28              0.0
21         1      20           29    0.11926219607
22         1      20           30              0.0
23         1      20           31   0.128091658298
24         1      21           32   0.264369876118
25         1      21           33              0.0
26         1      21           34   0.136801239629
27         1      21           35   0.172101959022
28         1      21           28   0.289540759798
29         1      21           29              0.0
30         1      21           30   0.519869498363
31         1      21           31              0.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andrej for answering the question,